# WordPress and Visual Composer custom page template

Tags: wordpress, templates

I really hope somebody can help me.
I'am working with visual composer and whould like to create a template to use on some page's.

I whant to create  the first section in pure code and  save it in my theme's as a template file.

Then when i pick this template in the page editor, i whould like to use visusal composer, but content made with composer should go below, what i have done in my theme's templatefile.

So if my template file in my theme folder contains a big image and some buttons, then i whant to output visual composer content below it.

Is that at all possible.?

When i try to pick another template file then the default i just get a blank output containing header and footer but no content from visual composer. When i use the default template, all works.

I whant to create a file where i can tell visual composer where to output content, hope it makes sense.

Kind regards 
Dannie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible.

Below is a code-example of the template file where you can add your custom code wherever you like.

Name your file like this `example-page.php`
The ID's and classes are of course optional.

```
<?php
// Template Name: Your name

get_header(); ?>

<!-- Your custom code goes here -->

<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
        <div class="container">

            <!-- Or here, if you want it inside your container -->

            <div>
                <?php
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                    the_content(); // Will output the content of visual composer


                endwhile; // End of the loop.
                ?>
            </div>

        </div><!-- END container -->
    </main><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
```

Need more instructions? Please let me know :)